# Cannot replace substrings by using zip method

Tags: python, pandas

To all,

I have a dataframe with 104959 rows and 298 columns.

To replace substrings in particular column I've tried:

```
# 위에서 치환한 문자열들을 맞게 바꿔줍니다
df['EVENT_DTL'] = df['EVENT_DTL'].replace(dict(zip(['발견장소_1','발견장소_2','발견장소_3','발견장소_4','발견장소_5','발견장소_6','발견장소_7','발견장소_8','발견장소_9'],
                                     ['자택','친척 집','지인 집','학교 혹은 직장','공공장소','숙박업소','교외 혹은 야산','병원',''])))
```

But it hasn't changed at all when I `print(df.loc[2143,'EVENT_DTL'])`

I've used this method since classic replace method such as `df.replace({'발견장소_1':'자택','발견장소_2':'친척 집'},inplace=True)` doesn't work

`df['EVENT_DTL']` looks like this:

```
1. 변사자 정보 : 
2. 발견일시 : 2013year05month18day 13:00
3. 발견장소 : 
1) 수사기록 상 주소 
주민등록상 주소 : Seoul 
실거주지 주소 : Seoul Jongro 
시도(발견)장소 주소 :  Seoul Jongro Euni
2) 실제 조사원이 입력한 주소
주민등록상 주소 : 
실거주지 주소 : 
시도(발견)장소 주소 : 
조치(사유 포함) :
4. 발견장소 코딩사유 : 발견장소_1 / nan_nan
5. 방법/수단 : MAIN_METHOD_8
6. 발견경위 : 
7. 주원인 코딩사유 : 
8. 기본배경정보 : 
9. 사회경제적상태 : 
10. 성격 : 알수없음
11. 대인관계 : nan대인관계문제_88애인 관련_nan친구 관련_nan직장 내_nan소외 문제_nan
12. 정서상태 : 
13. 경찰 최종자살판단유무 및 내용 : 주원인_3_수면제_nan진통제_nan병원에서 처방 받은 약물_nan기타약물_nan 농약_nan 살충제_nan 제초제_nan 쥐약_nan 화학약품_nan 목매달기_1.0 가스 질식_2.0 물에 뛰어들기_2.0 뛰어내림_2.0nan 칼, 송곳으로 찌르기nan
14. 코로나와의 관련성 : nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `regex = True`

```
d = dict(zip(['발견장소_1','발견장소_2','발견장소_3','발견장소_4','발견장소_5','발견장소_6','발견장소_7','발견장소_8','발견장소_9'],
                                     ['자택','친척 집','지인 집','학교 혹은 직장','공공장소','숙박업소','교외 혹은 야산','병원','']))
df['EVENT_DTL'] = df['EVENT_DTL'].replace(d, regex = True)
```

Comment: question. why do I need regex in this syntax? Cause I can't find any regular expression here